# Unavailable port 443 after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, tomcat, port, autostart

I am new in Linux.

I have installed on my Debian server Tomcat9. Tomcat is running after OS reboot, but port 443 is not listen. I can run tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh a then tomcat/bin/startup.sh and then port 443 is listen OK.

But I need to run Tomcat with 443 automatically.

I have enabled 443 in server.xml and tomcat is started with tomcat.service file in /etc/systemmd/system.

Comacat logs contain these records after restart the machine:

localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log

```
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.783 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.783 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log

```
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.739 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.746 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.752 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.801 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.806 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.819 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
18-Dec-2019 10:22:02.819 INFO [Thread-9] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

443 is unavailable after restart the daemon, too. According to `sudo lsof -i:443` it seems that port 443 is not using. I don't have apache installed.

I guess that tomcat bound to 0:0:0:0, but I rather join result of `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`:

```
tcp  0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 987/sshd 
tcp6 0 0 :::11443 :::* LISTEN 838/java 
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 987/sshd 
tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN 1133/java 
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:11005 :::* LISTEN 838/java 
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8005 :::* LISTEN 1133/java 
tcp6 0 0 :::11080 :::* LISTEN 838/java 
tcp6 0 0 :::8009 :::* LISTEN 1133/java 
tcp6 0 0 :::65452 :::* LISTEN 578/java 
tcp6 0 0 :::36751 :::* LISTEN 578/java
```

I am using jre 1.8.0_192.

Server.xml configuration:

```
<Connector     port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                    clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
                    keystoreFile="/opt/conf/cert/mesto-most-crt.pfx"
                    keystoreType="PKCS12"
                    keystorePass="secret"
                    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
     />
```

Comment: is tomcat bound to localhost or to 0:0:0:0? And AFAIK Tomcat won't support HTTPS out of the box, which is one reason why it is used with an Apache/Nginx front-end.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this...

Comment: `tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN 1133/java` shows that process 1133 is listening to port 443 on IPv6 which by default will also accept IPv4 connections.

Comment: How can I fix it?